# how to export the data edited to a new excel file

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning

The provided code imports the excel file and removes the not NaN values and store it in df2. Now, How do i save the changes to an another file.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx')
df2 = df1[pd.isnull(df1['column_name'])]
df2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use:

```
df2.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

I suggest you take some time to look at the various functionalities pandas offers. Will be great help to you in future!